# How to properly import screens in the same directory?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm new to `react-native/expo`, and I'm currently trying to test my code and make sure that I set up `react-navigation` properly. When I try to run on expo on my smartphone, I get back this:

> Unable to resolve module './screens/RegistrationScreen' from
>   'C:\Users[username]\Desktop\JDA\Smartbox\screens\HomeScreen.js': The
>   module './screens/RegistrationScreen could not be found from
>   'C:\Users[username]\Desktop\JDA\Smartbox\screens\HomeScreen.js'.
>   Indeed, none of these files exist...

I'm not exactly sure if I'm writing the directory wrong or not, but I can't seem to find many other situations where this is happening and find a proper solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { WebBrowser } from 'expo';

import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import RegistrationScreen from './screens/RegistrationScreen';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={[{flex: 1}, styles.container]}>
      <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>Manage my locks</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 2}}/>
      <Button style={{flex: 1}}title="Registration Test" onPress={this.onPress}>
      </Button>
      <Button style={{flex: 1}} title="Add new lock">
      </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight + 15
      }
    })
  },
  developmentModeText: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 19,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    paddingTop: 30,
  }
});

createStackNavigator({
  Register: {
    screen: RegistrationScreen
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
});
```

The header from RegistrationScreen is like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Button,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View

} from 'react-native';

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

The HomeScreen and Registration Screen are in the same directory. I'm just doing this for testing, but I want to be sure that I can navigate from this screen to registration once I press the button.

Comment: I'm thinking there's a issue with how you export modules.  "HomeScreen and Registration Screen are in the same directory" but not in the same file?  Are they export defaults? If so, lose the curly braces.

Comment: screens should always be export default and when import they should'nt be with curly braces, also an error i encountered before is u cant use a screen with lowercase first letter it should always be uppercase

Comment: post your project folder structure, maybe you are importing the screens wrongly

Comment: C:\Users\Brooklyn\Desktop\JDA\smartbox\screens is the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Since your HomeScreen and RegistrationScreen are in same directory your import of HomeScreen should be

```
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
```

instead of

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

and of RegistrationScreen should be

```
import RegistrationScreen from './RegistrationScreen';
```

instead of

```
import RegistrationScreen from './screens/RegistrationScreen';
```